# JavaFX ComboBox not showing same value on selection in dropdown after resetting previous selection

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-2

I am facing a issue with JavaFX 2.2 [ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) while selecting a same value again after I reset previous selection of that value. I could not see that value selected in the drop down.

I also tried example given on documentation site - [Editable Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm). Followed below steps -

1. Select any email address.
2. Select Priority drop down value as 'High' then input Subject and email body.
3. Click on 'Send' button. We get successful message to email sent and it clear out the mail address and Priority drop down.
4. Now select Priority drop down value as 'High' you won't see any value selected in that drop down.

However when I select drop down value other than previously selected then I can see that value selected in drop down. I am facing same problem in my application. Why selected value is not visible in drop down and what would be fix/workaround for it? Any help really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a ComboBox named cbNav it was created with SceneBuilder and when the Controller Class loads I use this code to RESET the ComboBox

```
public void setData(){
    cbNav.getItems().clear();
    //cbNav.setValue(null);
    cbNav.getItems().addAll("To 1","To 2","To 3");
    cbNav.setPromptText("Click Me:");
}
```